# Should I transform this char number to decimal and after that to binary or?

Tags: c

Write a program that will input a  number on 8 bits of type char from the keyboard (-128  to  127). Convert  this  number  to binary  using a  helper  function get_bit that will take as input parameters the bit number to be tested and the initial number. The function will return 0 or 1 according to the bit tested. Create  an  array  of  8  values such  that  each  value  is  the  result  of get_bit for its corresponding index. Then display the values of the array.

I tried altoi and sscanf but my code shoud take a number that i type in and for whatever reason it seemes that is not working.
`

```
int main(void) 
{ char *num;
int tr_num;
 uart_init(); // open the communication to the microcontroller
 io_redirect(); // redirect input and output to the communication
 printf("Type a number:");
 scanf("%c",&num);
 int val =atoi(num);
 printf("%d",val);
```

`

Comment: There is no such thing as a decimal. "decimal" is a notion of input output: how an integer is written or read. But an integer is an integer. It has no base. You can't convert it from one base to another, since it has no base. (I understand that your statement, wrongly, use the word "convert" for binary base, but, even if the word is incorrect, in that context, it designates something possible: to create a binary representation of an int. But that is just a representation. The int itself has no base. And `char` in C is just a type of integers.)

Comment: I think you just want to do `int val = num;`, maybe?

Comment: user2055066, Save time for you and us.  Enable all warnings and a good compiler report report trouble with `char *num; ... scanf("%c",&num);`.

Comment: `atoi(num)` expects `num` to point to a _string_.  Since `num` does not point to a _string_, this is _undefined behavior_ (UB).